# Change the default html select list anchor points from top left to top right

Tags: javascript, css, select

I am trying to change the default html select box anchor points from top left to top right is this possible? I have searched but cant find anything online.

Comment: What do you mean by "anchor points"?

Comment: By "anchor points" i am referring to how the options in the select list are positioned. By default they are anchored from top-left. I want to change that because some of the elements in the list are long and stretch off the screen if you don't have a wide screen. By anchoring the options top-right all the elements will be seen even on a smaller screen.

Comment: here is the url: www.jamaicatoursltd.com

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to change that at all. But browsers should make sure the whole menu is on the screen if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This works unfortunately only in FF:

```
<select dir="rtl">
```

Comment: I have tried it and it works well on chrome,FF and even on ie given a few tweeks. Thank you very much for your awesomeness.